# `ceqn` environment for centred equations does not work

Tags: spacing, equations

If I try to center this my equation with `ceqn` it does not work for me. If i use `gather` I get what I want but my editor (Overleaf) gives me an error that I used `alignat` inside `gather`. What can I do to solve my problem? 
Code:

```
\begin{ceqn}
    \begin{alignat*}{2}
      &\mathllap{u(0)}  = \quad    && 0,367061551548078427747792113175610961512192053613139 \\
      &\mathllap{u'(0)} = \quad  - && 0,295372105447550054557007047310237988227233798735629
    \end{alignat*}
\end{ceqn}
\begin{gather*}
    \begin{alignat*}{2}
      &\mathllap{u(0)}  = \quad    && 0,367061551548078427747792113175610961512192053613139 \\
      &\mathllap{u'(0)} = \quad  - && 0,295372105447550054557007047310237988227233798735629
    \end{alignat*}
\end{gather*}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: And where exactly should ceqn come from? To use alignat inside gather used alignedat. Most ams math env like that also have "inner" versions. Additional always post full but minimal examples not out of context sniplets like this where we have to guess a lot to even test the code

Comment: @daleif It seems an abbreviation of center equation.

Comment: @Sebastiano which makes no sense as the are already centered hence the request for a full example

Comment: @daleif Absolutely I am agree with you.

Comment: I understand your remarks, I'll think about it next time I ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will never get perfect centering with `\mathllap`.

Use a phantom, instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % just for showing the page margins

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
u(0)  &= \hphantom{-}0{,}367061551548078427747792113175610961512192053613139 \\
u'(0) &=           - 0{,}295372105447550054557007047310237988227233798735629
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % just for showing the page margins

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
u(0)  &=  && 0{,}367061551548078427747792113175610961512192053613139 \\
u'(0) &= -&& 0{,}295372105447550054557007047310237988227233798735629
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]